# AMChart v4 Stacked Column Chart width column from data series

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I need assistance with this famous plug-in.
I'm using the chart "Stacked Column Chart" for create a "Mekko Chart" because in v4 is not native.
I did it, but I don't know how to implement dynamic width based on the series.

Here the code:

```
function am4themes_colorRiskScore(target) {
          if (target instanceof am4core.ColorSet) {
            target.list = [
              am4core.color("#D6EAD6"),
              am4core.color("#D6EBC1"),
              am4core.color("#FAF3BA"),
              am4core.color("#FAE3C9"),
              am4core.color("#EDC8CC"),
              am4core.color("#000000")
            ];
          }
        }

      am4core.useTheme(am4themes_colorRiskScore);
      var chart = am4core.create("mekkochart", am4charts.XYChart);
      chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

      chart.data = [];

      chart.padding(30, 30, 10, 30);
      chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

      var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 90;
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 13;
      categoryAxis.renderer.showAllValueLabels = true;
      categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
      categoryAxis.renderer.width = 0.5;
      console.log(categoryAxis.renderer.width);

      var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.min = 0;
      valueAxis.max = 100;
      valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
      valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;
      valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 50;


      var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series1.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series1.columns.template.tooltipText =
        "{name}: {valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}% ({valueY})";
      series1.name = "Low Risk";
      series1.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
      series1.dataFields.valueY = "Low";
      series1.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
      series1.dataItems.template.locations.categoryX = 0.5;
      series1.stacked = true;
      series1.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

      var bullet1 = series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
      bullet1.interactionsEnabled = false;
      bullet1.label.text = "{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}%";
      bullet1.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");
      bullet1.locationY = 0.5;

      var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series2.columns.template.tooltipText =
          "{name}: {valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}% ({valueY})";
      series2.name = "Medium Risk";
      series2.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
      series2.dataFields.valueY = "Medium";
      series2.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
      series2.dataItems.template.locations.categoryX = 0.5;
      series2.stacked = true;
      series2.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

      var bullet2 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
      bullet2.interactionsEnabled = false;
      bullet2.label.text = "{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}%";
      bullet2.locationY = 0.5;
      bullet2.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");

      var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series3.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series3.columns.template.tooltipText =
        "{name}: {valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}% ({valueY})";
      series3.name = "High Risk";
      series3.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
      series3.dataFields.valueY = "High"; 
      series3.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
      series3.dataItems.template.locations.categoryX = 0.5;
      series3.stacked = true;
      series3.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

      var bullet3 = series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
      bullet3.interactionsEnabled = false;
      bullet3.label.text = "{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}%";
      bullet3.locationY = 0.5;
      bullet3.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");

      var series4 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series4.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series4.columns.template.tooltipText =
        "{name}: {valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}% ({valueY})";
      series4.name = "Significant Risk";
      series4.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
      series4.dataFields.valueY = "Significant";
      series4.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
      series4.dataItems.template.locations.categoryX = 0.5;
      series4.stacked = true;
      series4.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

      var bullet4 = series4.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
      bullet4.interactionsEnabled = false;
      bullet4.label.text = "{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}%";
      bullet4.locationY = 0.5;
      bullet4.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");

      var series5 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series5.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series5.columns.template.tooltipText =
        "{name}: {valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}% ({valueY})";
      series5.name = "Critical Risk";
      series5.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
      series5.dataFields.valueY = "Critical";
      series5.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
      series5.dataItems.template.locations.categoryX = 0.5;
      series5.stacked = true;
      series5.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

      var bullet5 = series5.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
      bullet5.interactionsEnabled = false;
      bullet5.label.text = "{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.0')}%";
      bullet5.locationY = 0.5;
      bullet5.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");

      chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

And here an example of series:

```
chart.data = 
[{
  category: 'Germany',
  id: 1,
  Low: 4,
  Medium: 5,
  High: 0,
  Significant: 10,
  Critical: 8,
  point: 0.4
},
{ category: 'Italy',
  id: 2,
  Low: 2,
  Medium: 10,
  High: 0,
  Significant: 4,
  Critical: 2,
  point: 0.8
}]
```

where point is a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Is there any good soul who could help me?

Comment: Mekko charts are not supported in v4 at this time due to the lack of the dynamic width capabilities. You'll need to use v3.

Comment: WHAT???? Are you sure? But v3 Legacy libraries are included into v4 or I must add to code?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive (as noted in my profile, I *do* work for AmCharts, so I don't know how much more confirmation you need :) ). AmCharts v4 licenses include AmCharts v3 licenses so for the rare instance you need some functionality that isn't in v4, you can include the v3 library and use that instead. They don't conflict with each other, so you can safely use both versions in the same page/app.

Comment: @xorspark Tks ;)